# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I am try to connect my Spring boot rest api with google cloud mysql . When i run my spring project i encounter an error that "org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement"
, But the same code  work with workbench without any problem.

```
@Data
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity


public class Customer {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String gender;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Product.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name ="cp_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Product> products;
    

}

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity

public class Product {

    @Id
    private int pid;
    private String productName;
    private int qty;
    private int price;
}

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://"myapiIadres"/SellingSystem
spring.datasource.username=roots
spring.datasource.password=data4321@
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Answer (score 1):

As told in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq), Cloud SQL for MySQL supports only innoDB:

> For MySQL instances, InnoDB is the only storage engine supported.

Consequently one should use dialect that targets to InnoDB storage engine. Optimal dialect tends to vary based on version of MySQL and Hibernate. Following is likely fine, as according [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/db-versions) default MySQL version is 5.7.x.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect
```